# Convert DataFrame to JSON with single array

Tags: r, api

Let's say I have the following data....

```
areaId <- "abc123"
time <- format( seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+1), by = "5 min"),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
value <- 10
df <- data.frame(areaId, time, value)
```

Giving output

```
$ areaId <chr> "abc123", "abc123", "abc123", "abc123", "abc123", "abc123", "abc123", "abc123", "abc123", "abc123", "abc123", "abc12…
$ time   <chr> "2022-01-30 00:00:00", "2022-01-30 00:05:00", "2022-01-30 00:10:00", "2022-01-30 00:15:00", "2022-01-30 00:20:00", "…
$ value  <dbl> 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, …
```

How can I convert into a JSON file that looks like this so I can POST to an API... everything I've tried so far gives me 3 individual arrays rather than 1.

```
{
    "nameofdata": [
        {
            "areaId": "abc123",
            "time": "2022-01-30T00:00:00Z",
            "value": 0,
        },
        {
            "areaId": "abc123",
            "time": "2022-01-30T00:05:00Z",
            "value": 0,
        },
        {
            "areaId": "abc123",
            "time": "2022-01-30T00:10:00Z",
            "value": 0,
        },
...
    ]
}
```

Many thanks for any assistance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(jsonlite)
toJSON(list(nameofdata = df), pretty = TRUE)
```

which gives:

```
{
  "nameofdata": [
    {
      "areaId": "abc123",
      "time": "2022-01-30 00:00:00",
      "value": 10
    },
    {
      "areaId": "abc123",
      "time": "2022-01-30 00:05:00",
      "value": 10
    },
    {
      "areaId": "abc123",
      "time": "2022-01-30 00:10:00",
      "value": 10
    }
…
  ]
}
```